# What is the implementation cost threshold for a requested reasonable adjustment to become unreasonable?

Tags: england-and-wales, equality-act-2010, reasonable-adjustment, disability

Under the equality act 2010 one may request structural adjustments to premises Abe other adjustments at the service provider’s expense. How much must these cost to implement before they are considered to be unreasonably expensive?

Are there any landmark cases that distill certain fundamental guiding principles for determining when an adjustment is unreasonably expensive or reasonably requirable?

Comment: Is this service related to the persons employment ? Or, like the ramp, needed to navigate the building. Elevator controls? Kiosk for getting coffee?

Comment: I wasn’t aware that there were different definitions of reasonable for different types of adjustments.

Comment: Unless you get this I to the realm of employment or public accommodation I do not think anyone will be required to modify a product for you.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite on what basis do you say this?

Comment: It was a comment rather than an answer since it is not definitive. As others have said, requirements to respond to disabilities of prospective users will depend on the context and you have not clearly specified it.

Answer (score 5):

### Whatever is reasonable in the circumstances

There is no fixed amount, that’s why they used the word “reasonable”. It depends not just on the cost, but the resources of the employer, the value-add the employee brings, the time it takes and the inconvenience it causes.

I found this [compendium](https://equineteurope.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Annex-_Reasonable-Accomodation.pdf) of case outcomes from 2021 covering the entire EU.

Comment: It’s not only in the context of employees but also of disabled users of services who need to access the premises. And the question is obviously interested in the question as to whether or not this obvious vagueness has ever been clarified by case law.

Comment: @Seekinganswers for a question to be “obviously” about something, it should mention that something.

Comment: Well I would disagree: unlike robots humans can often read things with regard to nuance and insinuation, including obvious insinuations. Yet the compendium is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @TylerDurden yes, they can, however, it’s the *writer’s* job to communicate their intent, not to rely on the reader to infer it. That type of reasoning on the part of writers is why I get paid a lot of money resolving disputes.